# Unable to connect to server following phpMyAdmin upgrade from 5.1 to 5.2

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Working environment:

- OpenSUSE Leap 15.4
- MariaDB : mariadb Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.7.7-MariaDB
- PHP 8.0.25 (cli) (built: Oct 31 2022 12:00:00) ( NTS )

Based on phpinfo(), PHP ini file is: `/etc/php8/cli/php.ini`.

**phpMyAdmin 5.1 is working well**. Installation directory is: `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin` (default directory created when installing *via* `zypper install phpMyAdmin` command).
The "famous" option `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']` from `/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php` file is set to `localhost` (and it does work!).

I have then upgraded phpMyAdmin version this way:

```
srv-bla:~ # mv /usr/share/phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin.old
srv-bla:~ # mkdir /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
srv-bla:~ # wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/5.2.0/phpMyAdmin-5.2.0-all-languages.tar.gz
srv-bla:~ # tar -xzf phpMyAdmin-5.2.0-all-languages.tar.gz
srv-bla:~ # mv phpMyAdmin-5.2.0-all-languages/* /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/
```

I then restart daemons and test the connection:

`srv-bla:~ # systemctl restart mysqld mariadb apache2`

The connection page is showing right. I then enter my credentials and I get stuck with this bloody message:

> Impossible to connect to server.
> mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

I have wandered for a while on numerous webpages. Many of them suggest to modify the `config.inc.php` file and to set `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']` option to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. Unfortunately, **this does not fix the problem for me...**

Am I editing the right `config.inc.php` file? Actually, I can find only one on the server:

```
srv-bla:~ # updatedb
srv-bla:~ # locate config.inc.php
/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php
/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php.rpmnew
/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php.rpmsave
```

Apache logs are not friendly either. Access logs returns 200 codes only, which seems normal to me (the phpMyAdmin webpage is served properly). Error logs are empty...
Mysql logs are empty also (`/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log`).

Or course, I have check that `mysqld` service (same as `mariadb` service) is running.

The socket file from MariaDB point of view is:

```
srv-bla:~ # mariadb -u root -p
Enter password:
MariaDB [(none)]> \s
[...]
UNIX socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
[...]
```

The php.ini file is configured the same way:

```
srv-bla:~ # cat /etc/php8/cli/php.ini | grep mysqli.default_socket
mysqli.default_socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

To me, there is no socket issue...

Comment: Does `php -i | grep socket` or output from `phpinfo()` shows the correct socket?

Comment: Yes it does! See the final part of my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right @Georg Richter!

Solution for me:

The PHP configuration file returned by `php -r 'phpinfo();'` command in a terminal is `/etc/php8/cli/php.ini`.

The PHP configuration file returned by the *phpinfo()* function called with a URL such as http://myserver.fr/phpinfo.php is `/etc/php8/apache2/php.ini`.

I modified the line `mysqli.default_socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` in this other configuration file and could call again phpMyAdmin with success. Note that emtying the browser cache was necessary!

Thanks for help, and hope this will help others!